# Reconstruct optimization problem from polygon

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In optimization, a function $Ax\leq b$ defines a convex polygon in $R^2$. I have a set of vertices from this polygon and now need to reconstruct the optimization problem that has the same convex polygon as a set of possible solutions (i.e. find $A$ and $b$). The thing is, how do I find $A$ and $b$?

E.g. if I had a triangle of vertices (0,1), (-1,0) and (1, 0) how could I find an optimization problem in the form $Ax\leq b$ that has this triangle as a set of possible solutions? I believe I need to find the line equations for each edge, but I don't know how to proceed afterwards the matrices.

Edit:
Going by Kroki's answer, suppose that the triangle vertices are at (0,2), (-2,0) and (2, 0)
$$ A = \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
-1 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 2\\
0 & -1 & 2 &  0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
$$ b = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Would that be right?

Comment: Actually, neither answer below answers your question. The $A,b$ are not unique, but the issue with the answers below is that they introduce an extra 'multipliers' parameter.

Comment: Tangentially related https://mathoverflow.net/q/97131/31729

Comment: Are $A$ and $b$ not unique even when you know it a LP and have the vertices? This is all the information that I have

Comment: Well, trivially you can reorder the rows, but you can always add duplicate rows or rows that are implied by the others. You would also need to know that it is bounded.

Comment: One computationally intensive way would be to reconstruct the faces of the set, picking all combinations of $n+1$ affinely independent subsets of the vertices and seeing if there is a direction that works for the remaining points. Many details omitted.

Comment: We are only working in $R^2$ and which vertices are connected is given. There is no problem in reordering the rows, but I see how you could add linearly depend rows to $A$

Comment: The question suggests $n$ not the specific case of the plane. If you know that $n=2$ there are better algorithms for determining the hyperplane description. Some version of gift wrapping being slow but easy to understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm

Comment: Indeed, I got it wrong in the question. You also don't need this algorithm, as which vertices are connected is also given, you have the whole shape of the polygon.

Comment: Ok, I did not mean to apply it directly, you need to do a little work. You can use a similar idea to determine the extrema and order and these combined will define the hyperplanes. My point was that being in the plane is a huge simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have the vertices $v_1, \ldots, v_m$, then

$$u = \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i v_i,\; \text{and}\; \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i = 1$$ you can take $$A = \begin{bmatrix}-\boldsymbol I & v_1 & \cdots & v_m\\ \boldsymbol 0^{\intercal} & -1 & \cdots & -1\end{bmatrix},\; x = \begin{bmatrix}u\\ \lambda_1\\ \vdots\\\lambda_m\end{bmatrix}\; \text{and}\; b = \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

and your polyhedra will be defined as $Ax = b$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. How would I define $\lambda_i$ and what is $u$?

Comment: You have vertices. So every point in your polyhedra is a convex combinaison of $v_i$. $u$ are the coordinates of points in the polyhedra.

Comment: Do you not need the condition $0\leq\lambda_i\;\forall i$ to make sure the parameters are in $[0,1]$?

Comment: That would describe the affine hull of the points.

Comment: @VincentBatens yes that is correct.

Comment: I've edited my question solving for $A$ and $b$ with $v = \{(0,2), (-2,0) and (2, 0)\}$ following what you have written. Are the matrices right?

Comment: You  need to add constraint that $\lambda_i \ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the set in question is the convex hull of the points $v_k$, let $V=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_n \end{bmatrix}$, $e=(1,...,1)^T$,
$A=\begin{bmatrix} -I & V \\
I & -V \\
0 & e^T \\
0 & -e^T \\
0 & -I \end{bmatrix}$,
$b=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Then, assuming that the set in question is the convex hull of the points $v_k$ we have that the set is $\{ x | A\begin{bmatrix} x \\ \mu \end{bmatrix} \le b, \} = \{ \sum_k \mu_k v_k | \sum_k \mu_k =1, \mu_k \ge 0 \}$.